# R fable logit transformed exponential smoothing forecast producing unexpected result

Tags: r, time-series, tsibble, fable, tidyverts

I have tried and tried to figure this out but am having no luck!!

I have constructed a model that aims to forecast a relatively short time series using an exponential smoothing method.  The results need to be constrained to between 0 and 1, so I use the scaled logit transformation detailed by the package authors [here](https://fable.tidyverts.org/articles/transformations.html).

The model works beautifully for over 1000 groups across my dataset, but a single group produces an unexpected forecast as shown in the reprex.

Note that very small changes will change the result.  For example, if I set `upper` to 1.1, the model looks much more sensible.  Likewise, if I reduce the value of the last number in `x`, the model produces a sensible result.

I'm afraid I just don't understand the methods here well enough to diagnose this.  Any help is much appreciated.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)

scaled_logit <- function(x, lower = 0, upper = 1) {
  log((x - lower) / (upper - x))
}
inv_scaled_logit <- function(x, lower = 0, upper = 1) {
  (upper - lower) * exp(x) / (1 + exp(x)) + lower
}
my_scaled_logit <- new_transformation(
  scaled_logit, inv_scaled_logit)

x = c(0.5156105, 0.5137760, 0.5275933, 0.5561075, 0.5722731, 0.6237780, 0.6243926, 0.6256203, 0.8582260)

tibble(time = seq(2004, 2020, by = 2), x = x) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = time) %>%
  model(fit = ETS(my_scaled_logit(x, lower = 0, upper = 1) ~ trend("Ad") + season("N"))) %>%
  forecast(h = 15) %>% autoplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is due to the numerical approximation used for the mean of a transformed distribution. You can try plotting forecast medians (which don't use numerical approximation) instead with `autoplot(point_forecast = lst(median))`.

Comment: Thanks Mitchell.  That solves the problem nicely!